# The ate-eight split?

Tags: english, ipa, american-english, diphthongs

The words "ate" and "eight" are supposed to be homophones in English, yet in *(thick)* Hungarian, Dutch and Swedish accents, they are not homophones. As a native Hungarian-speaker, I will attest to this:

- In the words *"ate"*, *"late"*, *"mate"*, *"Kate"*, *"make"*, *"cake"*, *"lake"*, *"mate"*, *"late"*, *"mane"*, *"lane"*, *"cane"*, I *(and other Hungarians)* pronounce /eɪ/ as a long monothong [eː]
- In the words *"eight"*, *"day"*, *"lay"*, *"may"*, *"ray"*, "*way"* and *"main"*, I *(and other Hungarians)* pronounce /eɪ/ as a long diphtohng [eːi̯]

A Dutch friend of mine attests that he does the same thing, saying that the English "ay" sound to him is sometimes equivalent to the Dutch "ee" /eː/, other-times to "eei" /eːj/ *(a diphthong I think doesn't even exist in Dutch)*

Is this an example of spelling pronunciation? Because I even hear the two words differently when listening to American English. Are my ears biased by the spelling?

Comment: I don't understand the Dutch part: do you mean that Dutch speakers also distinguish "eight" and "ate" when they speak English? If we cut out the claim about Swedish and Dutch, I guess the question is, what is your evidence that Hungarian speakers do this? For instance, do you have recordings and professional judgments from trained phoneticians?

Comment: By the Dutch part, I mean that one Dutch friend of mine also distinguishes between "eight" and "ate" when he speaks English. AS for professional judgements from trained phoneticians... no, I do not have that. No, I did not consult any professional. I simply happen to have first-hand experience with it, as both me, and other Hungarians (experience) distinguish the two words, and I can clearly tell the difference between a long monophthong and a diphthong.

Comment: In some British English dialects, *ate* is pronounced as `/ɛt/` contrasting *eight* `/eɪt/`, but none of the other words you mention have this vowel in these dialects, they are all `/eɪ/`.

Answer (score 4):

There are obscure British accents where words spelled with *eigh* like *eight* can have a different vowel from words spelled with "long a" like *late* or words spelled with *ay/ai/ey/ei.* This is not technically a split, but the lack of a merger that is present in nearly all other accents of English.

Historically, *eight* had a fricative consonant [ç] before the [t], which caused the preceding vowel to diphthongize, while the vowel in *late* comes from the Middle English monophthong [aː], which ended up being raised and fronted to [eː] and then diphthongized to its typical value of something like [eɪ~ɛɪ~ej~ɛj] in most accents.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_phonology#H-loss) says that in some accents, the vowel of words like *eight* and *weight* developed differently due to the presence of the fricative:

> /h/ spelled -gh- is realized as [x] even today in some traditional dialects of northern England and more famously Scots. Some accents of northern England lack the /x/, instead exhibiting special vowel developments in some such words; for example, *night* as /niːt/ (neat) and in the dialectal words *owt* and *nowt* (from *aught* and *naught,* pronounced like *out* and *nout,* meaning 'anything' and 'nothing'). Also, in northern England, a distinction is often preserved between the vowel /ɛɪ/ in words like *weigh, weight* and *eight,* and the /eː/ of *wait* and *late* (the northern realization of the vowel resulting from the *pane-pain* merger).

There is also a third set of words that can have a distinct vowel sound: certain words, usually spelled with *ay/ai/ey/ei,* that had some diphthong like [ai] or [æi] in Middle English. In most accents, this merged with the *late* vowel, but in some British accents, it remained distinct. Wikipedia says

> #### [Pane–pain merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_diphthongs#Pane%E2%80%93pain_merger)
>
> The *pane–pain* merger is a merger of the long mid monophthong /eː/ and the diphthong /ei/ that occurs in most dialects of English. In the vast majority of Modern English accents the vowels have been merged; whether the outcome is monophthongal or diphthongal depends on the accent. But in a few regional accents, including some in East Anglia, South Wales, and even Newfoundland, the merger has not gone through (at least not completely), so that pairs like *pane/pain* are distinct.
>
> A distinction, with the *pane* words pronounced with [eː] and the *pain* words pronounced with [æɪ], survived in Norfolk English into the 20th century. Trudgill describes the disappearance of this distinction in Norfolk, saying that "This disappearance was being effected by the gradual and variable transfer of lexical items from the set of /eː/ to the set of /æɪ/ as part of dedialectalisation process, the end-point of which will soon be (a few speakers even today maintain a vestigial and variable distinction) the complete merger of the two lexical sets under /æɪ/ — the completion of a slow process of lexical diffusion."
>
> Walters (2001)[8] reports the survival of the distinction in the Welsh English spoken in the Rhondda Valley, with [eː] in the *pane* words and [ɛi] in the *pain* words.
>
> In accents that preserve the distinction, the phoneme /ei/ is usually represented by the spellings ai, ay, ei and ey as in *day, play, rain, pain, maid, rein, they* etc. and the phoneme /eː/ is usually represented by *aCe* as in *pane, plane, lane, late* etc. and sometimes by *eCe* and *e* as in *re, cafe, Santa Fe* etc.

When words like *pain* and *pane* are distinguished by non-native speakers, it is most likely an example of spelling pronunciation. I know of no American English accent that has this distinction. Different accents of American English may have more or less use of a more monophthongal value [e] vs. a more diphthongal value like [ei̯], but these are allophones, not distinct phonemes. (I left out length markers because in English, phonetic vowel length is highly dependent on context: a vowel before a tautosyllabic phonologically voiceless consonant as in *wait* or *late* will be relatively shorter than a word-final vowel as in *way* or a vowel before a phonologically voiced coda as in *wage, paid*).

As other people have mentioned, the word *ate* is a special case: in a number of British English accents, the spelling has an irregular correspondence to the pronunciation, and the vowel may be short: /ɛt/.

Answer (score 4):

In England the “Received Pronunciation” (RP) of “ate” is [ɛt], so it is not the same as “eight” [eit]. But the difference that you make, and that you perceive, is clearly based on the orthography: where you see a diphthong you pronounce (and imagine to hear) a diphthong.

Comment: +1. Niggle: in RP, one of the *two* pronunciations used for *ate*  is /et/, while eight is always /eɪt/. In a narrow phonetic transcription, that would be [e̞t] and  [e̞ɪt] respectively, or if the fancy took you [ɛ̝t] and [ɛ̝ɪt]

Answer (score 2):

In some Northern Irish dialects of English, there is a 3 way distinction here, but not as you split it:

### `[ɛ]`

- ate
- says
- (take, make, lake, rake )<sup>1 2</sup>
- (bag, fag (feg), gag (geg), lag, nag, rag)<sup>2</sup>

### closed-syllabic `[eə ~ ɛə ~ ɪə ~ iə]`

- eight
- (ate), date, gate, hate, late, mate, rate
- bake, cake, take, fake, make, lake, rake
- daze, haze, laze, maze, phase, raise
- brave, gave, knave, save, rave

### open-syllabic `[eɪ]` / `[ɛː]`<sup>3</sup>

- bay(s), day(s), lay(s), ray(s), way(s), gay, hay, say
- tae

---

1. `/ɛ/` before `/k/` in Lagan Valley
2. `/ɛ/` before velars in broad, working-class Belfast dialect, now largely only before `/k/`
3. in open syllables a long monophthong near `[ɛː]` in broad, working-class Belfast dialect

---

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulster_English
- [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_diphthongs#Pane–pain_merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_diphthongs#Pane%E2%80%93pain_merger)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_phonology#H-loss